# UIWebView doesn't treat html properly

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am sending the following string to `UIWebView`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">
<img src="mysrc"></img>
</html>
```

However, when I read it with:

```
[templateWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">
<img src="mysrc">
</html>
```

With no end tag to `</img>`

How can I make `UIWebView` not to change the HTML tags?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question - I think you didn't post the original string you were sending.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even using private methods. WebKit discards "superfluous" closing tags and never lets them back.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the exact value in the "result", or did you just remove the ending tag manually to match what you see in the debugger? In other words, are you sure that the third line is `<img src="mysrc">`, not `<img src="mysrc"/>` (with a slash)?

Answer (score 0):

**IMG** is a self closing tag, so it should be:

```
<img src="mysrc" />
```

To be absolutely compliant with the standard it should also have ALT property defined:

```
<img src="mysrc" alt="something" />
```

That might be the cause of the parsing error.

Comment: in HTML img doesn't need to be closed

Comment: It doesn't need to be closed explicitly with a closing tag </img>, but it does need to end with a /> as I described. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2